# How can I customize the list of services that pops up when I choose to "share" something in an app?

Tags: share-menu

Many apps give you the option to "Share" whatever it is you are looking at (or watching or listening to).  This usually manifests in the form of a popup list of services that include: Gmail, Facebook, Twitter...)  The list seems to be the same from app to app.  How can I change what services are listed on this popup screen?  Is there any way to change, add, remove, append this list?

I'm running Android 2.2 on a Moto Droid 1.

Comment: One imagines editing the order would be almost as helpful. (Something that modified the order on basis of most recently used would be handy)

Comment: I added this [Android enhancement request](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24741)

Comment: Cool.  I starred your request.
The idea to allow the list to be sorted is also good.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The items in the list are determined by which installed apps support the `ACTION_SEND` intent.  Any app that supports that intent will be included in the list.  I don't think there is a way for users to modify the list other than installing/uninstalling applications.

Comment: This is kind of infuriating when about half of the apps that pop up for "share" are things I will never want to use.  Hopefully this will be addressed some day, even if only in a custom ROM.

Comment: Yep. So I'm u installing those.

Answer (score 4):

I personally use **[AppChooser Pro](http://www.appbrain.com/app/jp.co.noxi.apppickerpro)** for about a year already (there's also a [free version](http://www.appbrain.com/app/jp.co.noxi.apppicker) to test first if you like it). It's quite similar to *Andmade Share* which already was recommended with [an older answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/21427/16575), but first looks better (OK, that's quite subjective), but for me also works better, somehow more "intelligent":

[image: AppChooser List] [image: AppChooser Grid]
<sup>*AppChooser:* List and grid view (source: Google Play; click images for larger variants)</sup>

First, it offers a list *and* a grid view – as above screenshots show. You can switch between both using the appropriate icon on the bottom (in the middle; easy to identify in the screenshots). You can sort the list alphabetically, hide items you never (or rarely) use while still being able to show them “ALL” (appropriate icon again), select multiple targets, and more. By default, the list/grid order is kind of LRU: once you used a target, it will be moved to the top.

I immediately went for the paid version (not even taking a look at the free one), and never regret it. Differences between the two are listed on the Playstore page of the free version.

> Unfortunately, this app has been removed from the play store by the developer.

Comment: AppChooser Pro doesn't seem to be available on the Play Store either. There's an apk for AppChoose on [xda](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/themes-apps/app-app-chooser-default-app-manager-t2376603).

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the list, short of removing the apps in question. Speaking as an app developer, I can say it's also hard to do it from that side too - so we're pretty much stuck with how the system works.

It may be annoying, but the system makes interop so easy between applications, both from the user and developer perspectives, that it's hard to complain.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible from an OS level. That share menu is populated by Android based on what apps you've installed declare they can open. You can look at the technical details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html#ifs), but the end result is that without extra coding from each individual app to filter the results, you are always going to get the full list in whatever order Android returns them in.

Answer (score 1):

[Fliktu](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oakstar.fliktu) Not free but looks great, simple, customisable and very slick

[image: enter image deschhription here]

Answer (score 1):

SharedR does this nicely.
4.0 rating in google store

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rejh.sharedr