# Are there any custom ROMs which let the user somehow filter Share menu lists?

Tags: custom-roms, share-menu

Based on " [How can I customize the list of services that pops up when I choose to "share" something in an app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1156/how-can-i-customize-the-list-of-services-that-pops-up-when-i-choose-to-share-s/1158#1158) " answer, any app supporting ACTION_SEND intent will be listed in "Share" menu pop-up.

**Are there any custom ROMs which let the user somehow filter those Share menu lists to exclude installed apps?**

Comment: As developer, I thinks its quite difficult. Because you have to disable the broadcast receiver, which is not easy possible without editing the application which provide it.

Comment: @Leandros - I'm sorry, I'm not sure why? All it seems to need (from my NON android developer POV) is a patch to whichever code inside Android itself which generates the list, to be able to read some config file which blacklists or whitelists apps for inclusion. What am I missing?

Comment: Sounds easy. But isn't that easy.

Comment: @Leandros as with other broadcast receivers: as soon as a second registers, the user should be able to chose which becomes the default (see homescreens). My answer shows how this princip can be utilized.

Comment: @Izzy If I can find the time I'll implement it into AOKP.

Comment: Then send them the patch and let's pray they include it -- I'd like that as well!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's another [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/16575) question: you ask *how to establish your suggested solution,* instead to ask *how to solve your real problem*, which is your actual concern. For this task, you don't even need *any* Custom ROM.

Take a look at [Andmade Share](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andmadesoft.share) -- this app lets you customize your share menu on any ROM, not even root is needed:

[image: AnMade Share: Select Apps] [image: AndMade Share: Change Order]

As you can easily see, this app lets you...

- Select (filter) the apps appearing in the list (as your question required)
- Change the order in which they appear in the list (e.g. put your most frequently used apps on top)

Comment: Actually, I found Andmade Share recently (well after posting this question). While it's a nice idea and I love the app, on my fairly old DroidX, the app usually takes ~2-5 seconds to launch for whatever reason. Built-in share menu usually takes at most a second. There are benefits to not relying on an external app, evidently :)

Comment: Sure there might be, if there *were* any. So this app gives you an *existing* solution instead of a hypotetical one :)